# C++ template error

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I am learning C++ template, and I write a little algorithm. Unfortunately I got some errors
Here is my code

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename S, typename W>
void push(const T& value, deque<S>& original_stack, deque<W>& min_index)
{
  original_stack.push_back(value);
  if (min_index.size() == 0)
    min_index.push_back(0);
  else
    {
      if (value < original_stack[min_index.back()])
    {
      min_index.push_back(original_stack.size() - 1);
    }
      else
    {
      min_index.push_back(min_index.back());
    }
    }
}

template<typename S, typename W>
void pop(deque<S>& original_stack, deque<W>& min_index)
{
  original_stack.pop_back();
  min_index.pop_back();
}

template<typename T, typename S, typename W>
const T& min(deque<S>& original_stack, deque<W>& min_index)
{
  return original_stack[min_index.back()];
}

int main()
{
  deque<int> data_stack;
  deque<int> min_index;
  push(3, &data_stack, &min_index);
  push(4, &data_stack, &min_index);
  push(2, &data_stack, &min_index);
  push(1, &data_stack, &min_index);
  pop(&data_stack, &min_index);
  pop(&data_stack, &min_index);
  push(0, &data_stack, &min_index);
  cout<<"min num is: "<<min(&data_stack, &min_index)<<endl;
}
```

When I use g++ to compile it, I get this:

```
g++ minstack.cpp -o minstack
minstack.cpp:42:3: error: no matching function for call to 'push'
  push(3, &data_stack, &min_index);
  ^~~~
minstack.cpp:7:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'deque<type-parameter-0-1, allocator<type-parameter-0-1> >' against
      'std::__1::deque<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > *'
void push(const T& value, deque<S>& original_stack, deque<W>& min_index)
     ^
minstack.cpp:43:3: error: no matching function for call to 'push'
  push(4, &data_stack, &min_index);
  ^~~~
minstack.cpp:7:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'deque<type-parameter-0-1, allocator<type-parameter-0-1> >' against
      'std::__1::deque<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > *'
void push(const T& value, deque<S>& original_stack, deque<W>& min_index)
     ^
minstack.cpp:44:3: error: no matching function for call to 'push'
  push(2, &data_stack, &min_index);
  ^~~~
minstack.cpp:7:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'deque<type-parameter-0-1, allocator<type-parameter-0-1> >' against
      'std::__1::deque<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > *'
void push(const T& value, deque<S>& original_stack, deque<W>& min_index)
     ^
minstack.cpp:45:3: error: no matching function for call to 'push'
  push(1, &data_stack, &min_index);
  ^~~~
minstack.cpp:7:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'deque<type-parameter-0-1, allocator<type-parameter-0-1> >' against
      'std::__1::deque<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > *'
void push(const T& value, deque<S>& original_stack, deque<W>& min_index)
     ^
minstack.cpp:46:3: error: no matching function for call to 'pop'
  pop(&data_stack, &min_index);
  ^~~
minstack.cpp:26:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'deque<type-parameter-0-0, allocator<type-parameter-0-0> >' against
      'std::__1::deque<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > *'
void pop(deque<S>& original_stack, deque<W>& min_index)
     ^
minstack.cpp:47:3: error: no matching function for call to 'pop'
  pop(&data_stack, &min_index);
  ^~~
minstack.cpp:26:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'deque<type-parameter-0-0, allocator<type-parameter-0-0> >' against
      'std::__1::deque<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > *'
void pop(deque<S>& original_stack, deque<W>& min_index)
     ^
minstack.cpp:48:3: error: no matching function for call to 'push'
  push(0, &data_stack, &min_index);
  ^~~~
minstack.cpp:7:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'deque<type-parameter-0-1, allocator<type-parameter-0-1> >' against
      'std::__1::deque<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > *'
void push(const T& value, deque<S>& original_stack, deque<W>& min_index)
     ^
7 errors generated.
```

I am confused, could anyone help me to fix these bugs, I am kind of new to C++ template.

Comment: Why are you passing the *address* of your deques rather than their simple references as the functions call for? I.e. `push(3, data_stack, min_index);`

Comment: For me it looks bad that you have a function that acts with addresses on foreign objects. Smells like C code. I prefer OOP!

Comment: Why is `original_stack` of type `deque<S>` when you only ever push objects of type `T` into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass the addresses to the functions, the arguments are references not pointers

```
  push(3, data_stack, min_index);
  push(4, data_stack, min_index);
  push(2, data_stack, min_index);
  push(1, data_stack, min_index);
  pop(data_stack, min_index);
  pop(data_stack, min_index);
  push(0, data_stack, min_index);
```

And you need to explicitly tell the return type for `min`

```
cout << min<int>(data_stack, min_index) << std::endl ;
```

Or use:

```
template<typename S, typename W>
 typename deque<S>::value_type& min(deque<S>& 
                                  original_stack, deque<W>& min_index)
{
  return original_stack[min_index.back()];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a problem at the call site, e.g.:

> ```
> deque<int> data_stack;
> deque<int> min_index;
> push(3, &data_stack, &min_index);
> ```

If you compare the above `push()` function call with your `push()` template overload here:

> ```
> template<typename T, typename S, typename W>
> void push(const T& value, deque<S>& original_stack, deque<W>& min_index)
> ```

you can note that the second and third parameters are **references** (to some `deque` instances).

But at the call site you pass *addresses* of the `deque` instances, using the address-of operator (`&`), which would have worked if the parameters were defined as *pointers* (*not* references).

Since you opted for using references (and not pointers) in the function definition, then just get rid of the address-of operator at the call site.
This will be just fine:

```
push(3, data_stack, min_index); // References used
```

The same goes for the other function calls.

---

Note that this is a problem related to references vs. pointers. You can abstract away the template part, and just consider this simple C++ code to figure out the problem:

```
void f(int& n) {
    n++;
}

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    // f(&i); // <-- fails to compile
    f(i);
}
```

Since the f`()` function expects a *reference* to an `int`, then you don't want to pass the `int i` variable using a pointer at the call site: just pass `i` (not `&i`).

Answer (score 0):

```
original_stack.push_back(value); // T and S should have the same type or at least T should be derived from S
```

But that is not the problem.

```
int main()
{
  deque<int> data_stack;
  deque<int> min_index;
  push(3, data_stack, min_index);
  push(4, data_stack, min_index);
  push(2, data_stack, min_index);
  push(1, data_stack, min_index);
  pop(data_stack, min_index);
  pop(data_stack, min_index);
  push(0, data_stack, min_index);
  cout<<"min num is: "<<min(data_stack, min_index)<<endl;
}
```

As you can see, I removed al the address-of operators because you are passing by reference; You need to pass the address when your arguments are pointers.

Also, the return type of min should be S, because you return an element of the stack.
And you don`t even need W, because indexes are always ints.

Comment: `T` and `S` don't need to be derived or have the same type. `T` just needs to be convertible to `S`. If they were derived you would get slicing.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I didn't know how to express myself.