# C++ template error questions

Tags: c++, templates

I know there's a swath of C++ template questions circulating on SO like:

- [error: template argument required for 'struct List'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850809/error-template-argument-required-for-struct-list)
- [C++ template error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035498/c-template-error)

However, I'm currently battling against irksome `g++` errors:

```
In file included from LinkedList.cpp:1:0:                                                                                                                                
LinkedList.h:9:7: error: partial specialization 'class List<T>' does not specialize any template arguments                                                               
 class List<T>;                                                                                                                                                          
       ^                                                                                                                                                                 
LinkedList.h:15:51: error: expected class-name before '{' token                                                                                                          
 template <class T> class LinkedList : public List {                                                                                                                     
                                                   ^                                                                                                                     
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:                                                                                                                                      
LinkedList.h:9:7: error: partial specialization 'class List<T>' does not specialize any template arguments                                                               
 class List<T>;                                                                                                                                                          
       ^                                                                                                                                                                 
LinkedList.h:15:51: error: expected class-name before '{' token                                                                                                          
 template <class T> class LinkedList : public List {
```

My program is (for the sake of brevity) three files which include an "interface" `List.h` and a header-implementation file combo for a Linked List. As the compile errors suggest, there's an issue when extending the `List` interface in `LinkedList.h`. I'm not really sure why these are happening. I've tried solving the issue by using a mix of things like:

```
 template <class T>
 friend class List<T>;

 template<class T>
 class List<T>;
```

and doing:

```
 #include "List.h"
```

in both `LinkedList.cpp` and `LinkedList.h`

Here's `List.h`

```
#ifndef __A2_LIST_H__
#define __A2_LIST_H__

/**
 * A simple interface for creating new List classes.
 * This was chosen to reduce coupling between objects.
 */
template <typename T> class List {

public:
        virtual bool add(T data) = 0;
        virtual void add(unsigned index, T data) = 0;
        virtual void clear() = 0;
        virtual bool contains(T data) = 0;
        virtual T get(unsigned index) = 0;
        virtual unsigned indexOf(T data) = 0;
        virtual unsigned lastIndexOf(T data) = 0;
        virtual bool remove(T data) = 0;
        virtual T set(unsigned index, T data) = 0;
        virtual unsigned int size() = 0;
        virtual bool isEmpty() = 0;

};

#endif // __A2_LIST_H__
```

Here's `LinkedList.h`

```
#ifndef __A2_LINKEDLIST_H__
#define __A2_LINKEDLIST_H__

#include <cstddef>

#include "List.h"

template <class T>
class List<T>;

#if !defined(nullptr)
#define nullptr NULL
#endif

template <class T> class LinkedList : public List {

public:
    LinkedList(unsigned capacity);

    virtual bool add(T data);
    virtual void add(unsigned index, T data);
    virtual void clear();
    virtual bool contains(T data);
    virtual T get(unsigned index);
    virtual unsigned indexOf(T data);
    virtual unsigned lastIndexOf(T data);
    virtual bool remove(T data);
    virtual T set(unsigned index, T data);
    virtual unsigned int size();
    virtual bool isEmpty();

    void addFirst(T data);
    void addLast(T data);
    unsigned find(T data);

protected:
    class Node {
        public:
            Node(T data) {
                this->data = data;
            }   

            T data;
            Node *next, *previous;
    };  

    Node *head, *tail;

private:
    unsigned capacity, _size;

    LinkedList::Node* _seek(unsigned index);

};

#endif // __A2_LINKEDLIST_H__
```

and here's `LinkedList.cpp`

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

template <class T> LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(unsigned capacity) {
    this->capacity = capacity;
    this->_size = 0;
}

template <class T> bool LinkedList<T>::add(T data) {
    this->addFirst(data);
    return true;
}

template <class T> void LinkedList<T>::add(unsigned index, T data) {
    if(index > this->capacity) {
        throw "Index cannot be greater than the capacity";
    }   

    static LinkedList<T>::Node *node = new LinkedList::Node(data);

    if(index == 0 && this->_size == 0) { // adding to empty list
        this->addFirst(data);
    } else if(index == this->_size + 1) { // end of list
        this->addLast(data);
    } else { // somewhere in the middle
        LinkedList<T>::Node *fNode = this->_seek(data);
        if(fNode != NULL) {
            // TODO: insert new node here
        }   
    }   

    this->_size++;
}

template <class T> bool LinkedList<T>::isEmpty() {
    return this->_size == 0;
}

template <class T> unsigned LinkedList<T>::size() {
    return this->_size;
}
```

The thought process behind this is what I wanted to keep the coupling loose as a charge ahead on developing my application. Any advice on how to resolve this issue and why it's occurring is greatly appreciated. I am still very new to C++ so a lot of these issues are not-so-surprisingly cryptic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your LinkedList definition, try:

```
template <class T> class LinkedList : public List<T> { /*...*/ };
```

(note `List<T>` instead of just `List`)

There is also no need for the forward-declared `template <class T> class List` portion in LinkedList.h, as you are including the full class declaration.

Another thing worth noting is that your template class implementation should be in the header file too, rather than in a separate LinkedList.cpp file.  C++ cannot save binaries of template definitions, and they must be derived at compile time by being included in the headers.  It has enough sense to ensure they are only defined once though, unlike defining a non-template (and non-inline) function implementation in the header.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the tip, that squashed the remainder of my errors. I will keep that in mind for the future!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in `template <class T> List<T>` you should remove the `<T>` from the end of list, since you aren't specializing it, and I believe `template <class T> class LinkedList : public List {` should be `template <class T> class LinkedList : public List<T> {`